# How to str_replace text conditionally with if/not

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

After scraping a web page for its html, I need to replace text conditionally to correct links to the resources and media.

I need to replace the local links by replacing 'href="/' with 'href="http://example.com/' so that links will work, but while excluding anything like 'href="//' which will be links to offsite resources not using "http:/https:" for compatibility with and without SSL. So...

If 'href="/' or 'href=/'

But not if 'href="//' or 'href=//'

This didn't replace anything...

```
   $html = str_replace('href="?/(?!/)', $url, $html);
```

Meanwhile I am replacing // first:

```
    $html = str_replace('href="//', 'href="https://', $html);
    $html = str_replace('href=//', 'href=https://', $html);
```

Comment: If  `href="/` but if `href=/` how do you know the href if it's not delimited by a quote ?

Comment: otherwise, its simply `href="?/(?!/)`

Comment: $html = str_replace('href="?/(?!/)', $url, $html); did not do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `preg_replace` for regex replacement, not `str_replace`:

```
$tests = array("<a href=\"/",  "<a href=/", "<a href=\"//", "<a href=//");

$pattern = '/href=("?)\/(?!\/)/';

foreach ($tests as $test) {
  echo preg_replace($pattern, "href=\\1http://example.com/", $test);
  echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://example.com/
<a href=http://example.com/
<a href="//
<a href=//
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/SharpSmoggyNormalform#main.php)